# Persist Elastic Search Data in Docker Container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I have a working ES docker container running that I run like so

```
docker run -p 80:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name es-loaded-with-data --privileged=true --restart=always es-loaded-with-data
```

I loaded up ES with a bunch of test data and wanted to save it in that state so I followed up with

```
docker commit containerid es-tester
docker save es-tester > es-tester.tar
```

then when I load it back in the data is all gone... what gives?

```
docker load < es-tester.tar
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you started from the official ES image, it is using a volume (https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/7d08b8e82fb8ca19745dab75ee32ba5a746ac999/2.1/Dockerfile#L41). Because of this, any data written to that volume will not be committed by Docker.
In order to backup the data, you need to copy the data out of the container: `docker cp <container name>:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data <dest>`

Comment: I ended up figuring it out and thanks for the answer. The real crux of my issue was that the Dockerfile I was looking at that was checked into github did not have a VOLUME statement but the one used to build the ES docker image I was using was... That caused me serious confusion. Yes I used docker cp and now have a version that can load data on docker run using -v and also on that doesn't use a volume but obvioulsy makes a huge docker image. Thanks creack

Comment: If you're like me, using docker-compose.yml and have given your path to mount volume and it is not working then `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /path/to/volume` should work. worked in my case.

Comment: @ssi-anik , can you told me how to add  sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /path/to/volume  in the docker compose yml file?

Comment: you need to do this being on your host machine. not from docker-compose or docker file. rather run it on your local/server computer. @ManManYu